# How to modify the projection of a dataset in a ADF Dataflow

Tags: dataset, azure-data-factory, projection, dataflow

I want to optimize my dataflow reading just data I really need.

I created a `dataset` that maps a view on my database. This dataset is used by different dataflow so I need a generic projection.
Now I am creating a new `dataflow` and I want to read just a subset of the dataset.

Here how I created the dataset:

[image]

And that is the generic projection:

[image]

Here how I created the data flow. That is the `source settings`:

[image]

But now I want just a subset of my dataset:

[image]

It works but I think I am doing wrong:

I wanto to read data from my dataset (as you can see from `source settings` tab), but when I modify the projection I read from the underlying table (as you can see from `source option`). It seems an inconsistence. Which is the correct way to manage this kind of customization?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The solution proposed does not solve my problem. If I go in `monitor` and I analyze the exections that is what I saw...

Before I had applyed the solution proposed and with the solution I wrote above I got this:

[image]

As you can see I had read just 8 columns from database.

With the solution proposed, I get this:

[image]

And just then:

[image]

Just to be clear, **the purpose of my question** is:

How ca n I read only the data I really need instead of read all data and filter them in second moment?
I found a way (explained in my question) but there is an inconsistency with the configuration of the dataflow (I set a dataflow as input but in the option I write a query that read from db).

Answer (score 1):

First import data as a Source.

You can use `Select transformation` in DataFlow activity to select `CustomerID` from imported dataset.

Here you can remove unwanted columns.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-select

Comment: So, before I have to read all dataset and then make a projection. I cannot read directly only what I need

Comment: You can use a SELECT statement like you demonstrated above. Just leave the schema empty in the dataset and use the "Import Projection" button on the Source transformation.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt receive the notification. I tryed but perhaps I still make something wrong. I cannot click on `Import Projection`.  I updated the question with further details.

Comment: @Ciccio In Schema tab click on Import schema. After this, you will be able to Import projection

Comment: this not solve my problem... it is even worst respect the result I had some days ago.. Now I update the question and let you see